# Fatal Pear Error with form

Tags: wordpress

This form used to work: https://hej-support.org/subscription-chemicals-in-products-newsletter/

Now it gives back a
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _PEAR_call_destructors() (previously declared in /kunden/549141_85221/webseiten/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:773) in /kunden/549141_85221/webseiten/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/backwpup/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 812

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be due to the `backwpup` plugin enabled on your site. Try submitting the form after disabling the same.

This looks like a problem with this plugin. It was also raised on WP support - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-pear/

Comment: It works with WPBackup Plugin disabled, thank you. I will use another backup plugin untill the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the backWPup [tickets](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/conflict-with-civicrm-and-cron-jobs/) were closed with "The topic ‘Conflict with CiviCRM and CRON jobs’ is closed to new replies." I opend a [new ticket](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/conflict-with-civicrm-and-cron-jobs-2/).

As a weired workaround, I used the wp-cli approach, described in the [CiviCRM docu](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#wp-cli), created a php file that executes the wp-cli, and used an external cron service to start that php file.

wp-cli enables a temporary disabling of plugins, but this was not even necessary.